# store value obtained from dataframe

Tags: pandas

current_loc['percen_52week']=""

```
for i in current_loc.index:
         dff=week_high.loc[week_high['security_code']==current_loc['security_code'][i]]
            dff['week_high']=dff['week_high'].astype(float) 
            percen_52week=((1-current_loc['last'][i])/dff['week_high'])
            current_loc.loc[i,'percen_52week']=percen_52week
```

where current_loc and week_high are dataframes.

error:

```
 raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which pandas you are using but maybe this is the problem

```
current_loc.loc[[i,'percen_52week']]=percen_52week
```

I guess it should be

```
current_loc.loc[i,'percen_52week']=percen_52week
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally solved it , the issue was related to datatype ,here percen_52week was returning series datatype which cannot be allocated in current_loc

issue was solved when percen_52week was converted to float